# Images are not showing in homepage

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Images are not showing in homepage in wordpress website.But there is no problem in category page.Here is the link of website,

http://imsamma.com/

Comment: Please check image format first. Most of the people mistake it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS **Opacity** problem on that page use `opacity : 1;` insted of `opacity:0;`

```
body.td-animation-stack-type0 .td-animation-stack .entry-thumb, body.td-animation-stack-type0 .post img {
     opacity: 1; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot,It works

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your **style.css**

```
body.td-animation-stack-type0 .td-animation-stack .entry-thumb, body.td-animation-stack-type0 .post img {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot,It works

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
body.td-animation-stack-type0 .td-animation-stack .entry-thumb, body.td-animation-stack-type0 .post img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

To

```
body.td-animation-stack-type0 .td-animation-stack .entry-thumb, body.td-animation-stack-type0 .post img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot,It works